# My FLUTTER video app closes videos whenever my phone screen saver comes on

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using the Flutter Video Chewie package to show quite short videos about 4-5 minutes in length. However when playing the videos, when the phones screen saver timeout is reached the screen closes and stops the video.
I checked in the Chewie parameters and set the: AllowedScreenSleep parameter to false, however it still closes.
Is there a way in Chewie to make sure that this doesn't happen?

Many thanks any help with this as always appreciated.

Comment: you can use the Wakelock package if you want: https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this [dependency](https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock/install) and write this line when your video start playing *Wakelock.enable()* and when stop playing *Waklock.disable():

if you use this thing then your screen saver not get in picture while the video is playing :)

```
import 'package:wakelock/wakelock.dart';
// ...

// The following line will enable the Android and iOS wakelock.
Wakelock.enable();

// The next line disables the wakelock again.
Wakelock.disable();
```